# IgniteCache does not call loadCache()

Tags: java, spring, caching, ignite

I've followed [ignite documentation](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.0/docs/persistent-store#cachestore-example) and created my store adapter:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import javax.cache.Cache;
import javax.cache.integration.CacheLoaderException;
import javax.cache.integration.CacheWriterException;

import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.store.CacheStoreAdapter;
import org.apache.ignite.lang.IgniteBiInClosure;
import org.apache.ignite.resources.IgniteInstanceResource;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.my.calendar.dao.jpa.ChannelDetailsJpaRepository;
import com.my.calendar.entity.ChannelDetails;

@Service
public class CacheChannelStoreAdapter extends CacheStoreAdapter<Long, ChannelDetails> implements Serializable {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(CacheChannelStoreAdapter.class);

    private static ChannelDetailsJpaRepository channelDetailsJpaRepository;

    // Will be automatically injected. !!! apacheignite info, but it DOES NOT
    @IgniteInstanceResource
    private Ignite ignite;

    public Ignite getIgnite() {
        return ignite;
    }

    public void setIgnite(Ignite ignite) {
        this.ignite = ignite;
    }

    @Autowired
    public CacheChannelStoreAdapter(ChannelDetailsJpaRepository channelDetailsJpaRepository) {
        this.channelDetailsJpaRepository = channelDetailsJpaRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void loadCache(IgniteBiInClosure<Long, ChannelDetails> clo, Object... args) {
        LOGGER.trace("load cache...");
        super.loadCache(clo, args);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<Long, ChannelDetails> loadAll(Iterable<? extends Long> keys) {
        LOGGER.trace("load all. keys: {}", keys);
        return super.loadAll(keys);
    }

    @Override
    public ChannelDetails load(Long key) throws CacheLoaderException {
        LOGGER.debug("object to load: {}", key);
        return channelDetailsJpaRepository.findOne(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(Cache.Entry<? extends Long, ? extends ChannelDetails> entry) throws CacheWriterException {
        LOGGER.debug("object to save: {}", entry);
        Optional.ofNullable(entry)
                .map(Cache.Entry::getValue)
                .ifPresent(channelDetailsJpaRepository::save);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Object key) throws CacheWriterException {
        LOGGER.debug("object to delete: {}", key);
        Optional.ofNullable(key)
                .filter(Long.class::isInstance)
                .map(Long.class::cast )
                .ifPresent(channelDetailsJpaRepository::delete);
    }
}
```

The cache adapter has been injected into cache configuration `cacheConfiguration.setCacheStoreFactory(new FactoryBuilder.SingletonFactory<>(cacheStoreAdapter));`

---

I've got few issues at same time:

- do not see calling of `CacheStore.loadCache()` | `IgniteCache.loadCache()` (following documentations `@Override public ChannelDetails load(Long key)` should be called)
- do not see injected by ignite `@IgniteInstanceResource private Ignite ignite;`

Any ideas for fix or to check? ...may be i missed important part, where i should call cache loading directly in startTime or something else?

### Add more details

All cached data are saved into my db at caching time. At server starting server no data loads from db.

Cache configuration part for my adapter:

```
cacheConfiguration.setCacheStoreFactory(new FactoryBuilder.SingletonFactory<>(cacheStoreAdapter));
// Configure cache to use store.
cacheConfiguration.setReadThrough(true);
cacheConfiguration.setWriteThrough(true);
// Enable database batching.
cacheConfiguration.setWriteBehindEnabled(true);
```

Ignite starts in with web server (in same `jvm`, I know it's ugly, but it can not me reason of my broken test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignite does not call `IgniteCache#loadCache` method implicitly. You should do it yourself otherwise entry will be loaded from store only by get operations.

Also I've checked and sure that Ignite injects local instance to an store. How do you check it? Pay your attention that store instance can't be the same on all nodes in cluster. Ignite is distributed system and this object will be serialized and desirialized on all nodes and exactly this object (cacheStoreAdapter) might be have the filed `null`. You should see this injection when store will be called by Ignite.

Comment: `IgniteCache` is interface. I can have correspond object for this situation to be able call `loadCache` directly. I met it in documentation, I have not checked this case because of I do not know how to prepare variable `IgniteBiPredicate<K, V>` (...looking for examples of use)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Nikolay for his suggestion. He does not provided code, so I think would be good to know how it was solved in my case. I've got complete solution.

In `Ignite` configuration part we should call

```
igniteConcreteCache.loadCache(
    (IgniteBiPredicate) (key, val) -> {
        System.out.println(" =========>>>> Loading [key=" + key + ", val=" + val + ']');
        return true;
    });
```

To load data from storage we need override correspond method in `StoreAdapter`:

```
@Override
public void loadCache(IgniteBiInClosure<Long, ChannelDetails> clo, Object... args) {
    LOGGER.trace("load cache...");
    super.loadCache(clo, args);
}
```

should be :

```
@Override
public void loadCache(IgniteBiInClosure<Long, ChannelDetails> clo, Object... args) {
    LOGGER.trace("Load all cache data from db. this part should be used if Ignite starts.");
    if (args == null || args.length == 0) {
        channelDetailsJpaRepository.findAll()
                .forEach(channelDetails -> clo.apply(channelDetails.getId(), channelDetails));
    } else {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Handle to load objects by id collection.");
    }
}
```

This solution is not perfect (it has a lot of parts to do better) but it works and we can use it.

Comment: You can pass `null` as parameter for IgniteCache#loadCache(null). For example `igniteConcreteCache.loadCache(null)` It is not mandatory argument.

Comment: Following `Ignite` src `public void loadCache(@Nullable IgniteBiPredicate<K, V> p, @Nullable Object... args) throws CacheException` we can put `null` here - I agree with you. But in this case we should have workaround to put data into ignite cache. (Data have been just loaded, it is not added to cache yet). So I prefer parametrized case.

Comment: @Sergii: what do you mean by "Data have been just loaded and not loaded to Cache)... I have the similar situation and thought of using loadCahe(null)...is loading and adding to cache are not the same?? when you say data have been just loaded then where the data was loaded? isn't it loaded in cache?? 
Can you please enlighten me?

Comment: my requirement is to load all the data from data source to the Cache at once.. iterating thru the cache and put each entry is not encouraged in my case as per the requirement .. Please suggest
@NikolayTikhonov: please add your views as well